# How to make a transparent border

Tags: border, transparent

I want to do something like below. The border will be transparent and the background will look whatever color it is.

[image]

[image]

**Solution**
https://medium.com/@ventrebleu/the-case-for-crescent-shaped-avatars-2f4ccd48d053

Comment: What software are you using or expecting to do this in?

Comment: Excuse me for writing. I want to do it with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set the border to the background color.  I'm not sure if there's a blend-mode option. Below assumes:

1. the background color is solid
2. you can access the background color
3. you have control over setting the border color

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
}

circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: 0.5rem solid blue;
}

circle+circle {
  margin-left: -2rem;
}
```

```html
<container class="blue">
  <circle class="red"></circle>
  <circle class="green"></circle>
  <circle class="yellow"></circle>
</container>
```

### Comments

It is important to point out that this answer deviates slightly from what is being asked.  What is being asked is for a transparent border that subtracts from underlying elements and reveals the background (as a mask might).  Such that if the image was in the background, the image would be revealed between the spaces.

I don't know enough about CSS revelations to state if that's possible; it has certainly made advancements in blend modes and masking, so I won't stunt the possibility of shape clipping. I'll leave that to someone more experienced.